# Is there a traffic limit on Apple's Push Notification Service?

Tags: limit, push-notification, traffic

Is there a traffic limit on Apple's PNS?
Documentation says:

> You should also retain connections
>   with APNs across multiple
>   notifications. (APNs may consider
>   connections that are rapidly and
>   repeatedly established and torn down
>   as a denial-of-service attack.)

It seems to be heavy traffic allowed with only keeping connection.
Only rapid connect/disconnect case mentioned.

Really No traffic limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is what they say :-) So go for it!