# iOS app and APNS limits

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am building (well built) an app using Air and AS3 that uses push notifications. The app allows users to share information with other app users (open forum to all users) but I was wondering a few things which I couldn't find information on.

I have found some information but they seem old ([Is there a traffic limit on Apple's Push Notification Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170227/is-there-a-traffic-limit-on-apples-push-notification-service), [apple push notification limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421252/apple-push-notification-limitation)) so thought I would check.

1. How often am I allowed to query the APNS service? At the moment I queue all notifications in a table and once every 3 minutes I run a batch script to prepare the payload and send. There could be thousands of notifications to be sent every 3 mins.
2. Are there limits to how many notifications I can send hourly, daily, monthly etc

Users do have the option to turn off notifications in the app (and device) settings but thought I would check if someone knows this information.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

There is no limit for number of push notifications sent but you can not send duplicate notifications at random as the APNS server will ban your IP.
For better understandings,I think you should go over this-

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Comment: this is not true, no one will ban your ip address for sending more than one apns, how do you think viber and facebook work? wih the difference that they just keep the connecton alive...